# Does Webconfig in asp.net is same for Multiple Users or diffrent?

Tags: asp.net

Does Webconfig in asp.net is same for Multiple Users or diffrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings in `web.config` apply to the entire web application and are therefore global to all users of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Web.config acts as a central location for storing the information to be accessed by web pages.

Ex:Connection String stored in Web.config.It can be accessed in all pages. If the connection string changes its just a matter of changing it at one place.

It is same for Multiple user.